# NiFi Rest API: /access/token only works once

Tags: apache-nifi

System: NiFi 1.19, Java 11, Win 64bit, Auth: Username/password

NiFi Rest API:
I setup a postman collection for getting the access token.

At the first call, it works and NiFi returns a valid JWT-Token (checked with jwt.io )

nifi-user.log

```
2023-09-20 10:54:22,314 INFO [main] o.a.n.a.single.user.SingleUserAuthorizer Initializing Authorizer
2023-09-20 10:54:26,298 INFO [main] o.a.n.a.FileUserGroupProvider Users/Groups file loaded at Wed Sep 20 10:54:26 CEST 2023
2023-09-20 10:54:29,954 INFO [main] o.a.n.a.FileAccessPolicyProvider Authorizations file loaded at Wed Sep 20 10:54:29 CEST 2023
2023-09-20 10:54:29,970 INFO [main] o.a.n.a.single.user.SingleUserAuthorizer Configuring Authorizer
```

But since then I only get 403 forbidden

I crossed-check username/password: they are correct and I can login on the UI

login-identity-providers.xml

```
    <provider>
        <identifier>single-user-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authentication.single.user.SingleUserLoginIdentityProvider</class>
        <property name="Username">admin</property>
        <property name="Password">xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</property>
    </provider>
```

There is no error in *nifi-app.log*
In *nifi-request.log* there is only this information

```
10.90.30.28 - - [21/Sep./2023:08:38:48 +0000] "POST /nifi-api/access/token HTTP/1.1" 403 389 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.33.0"
```

Any idea, what's going wrong?
In which log should I look for more error information?

[image]

**Update 09/28/2023**: after Server-Restart the endpoint returns 201 and a token at the first call. Since then only 403. Do I have do add a right to the user?
[image]